# React import useState - require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Attempting to learn React, I have a very simple functional component with a State Hook. It seems like I cannot get the `import` statement to properly import `useState`, and I have console error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Is there anything else required here to get this component working?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const LikeButton = () => {
  const [liked, setLiked] = useState(0);

  if (liked) {
    return (
      <i className="fas fa-thumbs-down" onClick={() => setLiked(!liked)}/>
    )
  }
  return (
    <i className="fal fa-thumbs-up" onClick={() => setLiked(!liked)}/>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#like'));
root.render(<LikeButton />);
```

Comment: Run npm install, see if that helps.

Comment: Also, no need to use ReactDom, that should be done once in the index.js file to render app.js, all of that should be set up for you from the create react app script.  Then just add an export default Like button, and call the this component from app.js

Comment: you forgot to export your component, and no need to create root it's already created in root directory in index.js

Comment: also use jsx instead of `if` it's not functional that much on reactjs

Comment: @chikabala OP ***is*** using and returning JSX. The `if-statement` seems fine here. There are OFC ways to optimize/DRY-ify the code, but nothing inherently incorrect there with the `if-statement`.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah i didn't say it's false, i said `not functional that much`, so clearly he needs to check conditional rendering with jsx for future usage.

Comment: @DrewReese it means not gonna do the job for you all the time

Comment: @DrewReese not really, if he needs to show a span inside some divs, does he need to create 2 returns for that while he can just do conditional rendering on that span only ...

Comment: @wpw This isn't using `ceate-react-app`, I've just followed the instructions to add react to an existing website by adding the react script tags from their CDN

Comment: @noclist The best thing I could advise is dump react, write the plain old mark up/javascript/css.  Start messing around with React for small portions of your site and you will be bringing in all kinds of code you don't need.  BTW is "noclist" from mission impossible?

Comment: @WPW I'm just using my existing website as a tool for learning React, nothing for production purposes
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: @noclist where are you bringing in the cdn, that seems to be the issue, the react is being read before the code for react is there.

Comment: @WPW I've figured this out. I needed to use `React.useState(0);` instead of importing it from a node module that doesn't exist. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would think that importing React, you can use react functions implicitly. Haven't used react via cdn, learn sombin everyday

Comment: @noclist Since it wasn't mentioned you were trying to run React code directly in the html file your answer will make more sense in context if you edit your post to include the new and **very** relevant details for how you were trying to run the code and import and use React from a CDN. This would mean including the index.html file as part of your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `React.useState(0)` instead of the import statement.